# How to print a file in another file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

For example, if I have the file `A.dat` and `B.dat`and

A.dat have

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9

and the file `B.dat` is empty at first.

How can I (using Matlab functions) open the file `B.dat` print the `A.dat` content to it and print another entries like

> 10 11 12
>
> 13 14 15

?

I tried

`fileA=fopen('A.dat','r')`

`fileB=fopen('B.dat','w');`

`fprintf(fileB,fileA);`

or

`fprintf(fileB,fscanf(fileA));`

or

`fprintf(fileB,fscanf(fileA,'%s'));`

but none works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what the functions are used for. `fprintf`and `fscanf` are probably not what you are looking for (but can be useful).

Try using `fread` and `fwrite` instead:

```
dataA = fread(fileA)
fwrite(fileB, dataA)
```

Check the documentation for file operations at http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5702.html#f16-14516

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `fgets`.  `fopen` gives a file ID not the information in the file, so your first example won't work.

Assuming that your file is text (not binary) then something like the following should work to copy the file

```
fileA = fopen('A.dat','r');
fileB = fopen('B.dat', 'w');
while (line = fgets(fileA)) ~= -1
    fprintf(fileB, line);
end
fclose(fileA);
fclose(fileB);
```

`fgets` gives you an entire line (including newline characters) from a text file.

If your file is binary then something like the following would work

```
fileA = fopen('A.dat', 'r');
fileB = fopen('B.dat', 'w');
AData = fread(fileA);
fwrite(fileB, AData);
```

Note:  Unfortunately I don't have matlab on this computer so I couldn't test the examples.

For more info on the different file functions matlab has see:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5702.html#f16-14516

Comment: Well, I tried, but didn't work. Tried several variations of your code.

    fileA = fopen('A.dat','r');
    fileB = fopen('B.dat', 'w');
    while and(1,1)
        line = fgets(fileA));
        if  (line ~= -1) break;
        fprintf(fileB, line);
    end
    fclose(fileA);
    fclose(fileB);

The problem is in `while (line = fgets(fileA)) ~= -1`.

Tried, for example:

and didn't work too =//

Comment: My file is not binary (its spaces and numbers), but it works with your second and @kigurai 's code.

Comment: Well, I will test this out when I get a chance, but if you break it up like you did in your comment then you want to `break` when `line == -1` not when `line ~= -1`  Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop.  `fgets` returns -1 when it reaches the end of the file.  Thats why I was looping for as long as line wasn't -1.  fread and fwrite will work with text files as well, it will simply copy the file in bits form instead of text form.  In general that will make it difficult to modify and add lines to.

Comment: Thx. I tried `line==1` too, but I wrote wrong above. Thx about your time.